# Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?) - Angular 7 JIT

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, single-page-application

Hello i am facing issue which looks to be appear randomly. All my setup was working like charm.

I have couple of angular application compiled with webpack. all work fine in AOT but crash on JIT. It because the compiler are not able to understand annotation.

```
compiler.js:2700 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ApplicationModule: (?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2700)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:19254)
```

I use `"core-js": "^2.6.5"` (i have also try with `3.0.1`)

I have on my `polyfill.ts` all reflect as following :

```
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

my webpack configure contain following rules :

```
[
    {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: babelOptions
    },
    {
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        options: {
            transpileOnly: true
        }
    },
    {
        loader: 'angular2-template-loader'
    }
]
```

And my babel configuration looks like this :

```
presets: [
    [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        {
            modules: false,
            loose: true,
            targets: {
                browsers: [
                    "last 2 versions",
                    "not ie <= 10"
                ]
            },
            useBuiltIns: 'usage',
            corejs: "2",
            debug: false
        }
    ]
]
```

**What i have try so far ?**

- Upgrade and downgrade core-js.
- Upgrade and downgrade angular 7.

You can have look on minimal proof of issue on this [Github repo](https://github.com/yanis-git/multiple-angular-app)

Answer (score 3):

I have an Angular Application in v5 and recently upgraded to v9, purely add `import 'core-js/es7/reflect';` to the top of boot.ts or polyfill.ts cannot fix the problem

But once I load reflect-metadata in the very first line, everything fixed.

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

Comment: your'e the best

Answer (score 1):

You should only import

```
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

as it have been an issue in github page at [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/27531) and [here](https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/758)

The working repo [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-5xs2qx?file=src%2Fpolyfills.ts)

Comment: hello tony, thanks to have answer but is already what i have describe on my question. This polyfill is already loaded. You can have look on my repo if you want to experiment the issue by yourself.

Comment: Ok no worry i will take a look now

Comment: `npm install && npm run dev:app1`, then you can go to `localhost/path/to/src/app1.html`

Comment: Which port does the webpack run ? I can build it

Comment: i have not install and setup webpack-dev-server, you can use any web-server and navigate to src/app1.html.

Comment: I cant help you if you dont setup properly because I dont know how to run your project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193506/discussion-between-tony-ngo-and-yanis-git).